# Can't start managed server in Oracle Weblogic 10.3.2

Tags: oracle-11g, weblogic

I installed Oracle SOA Suite 11g.
I start the NodeManager successfully.
I start the AdminServer successfully.
When I go to start the soa serve (soa_server1) I get this output:

```
NMProcess: <Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM> <WARNING> <Exception while starting server 'soa_server1'>  
NMProcess: java.io.IOException: Server failed to start up. See server output log for more details.  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:331)    
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.handleStart(Handler.java:541)  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.handleCommand(Handler.java:116)  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.run(Handler.java:70)  
NMProcess:      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)  
NMProcess:
NMProcess: Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler handleStart  
NMProcess: WARNING: Exception while starting server 'soa_server1'  
NMProcess: java.io.IOException: Server failed to start up. See server output log for more details.  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:331)  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.handleStart(Handler.java:541)  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.handleCommand(Handler.java:116)  
NMProcess:      at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.run(Handler.java:70)   
NMProcess:      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)  
Error Starting server soa_server1: weblogic.nodemanager.NMException: Exception while starting server 'soa_server1'
```

In the log file I've got this:

```
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:27 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Starting WebLogic server with command line: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/bin/java -Dweblogic.Name=soa_server1 -Djava.security.policy=null -Djava.library.path="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64 server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/../lib/amd64:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/patch_wls1032/profiles/default/native:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/native/linux/x86_64:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib" -Djava.class.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/i18n.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/patch_wls1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/lib/tools.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/utils/config/10.3/config-launch.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.2.0.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/lib/ant-all.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.0.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbembedded57.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbclient57.jar:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbtools57.jar -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true weblogic.Server >  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:27 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Working directory is '/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/soa_domain2'>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:27 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server output log file is '/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/soa_domain2/servers/soa_server1/logs/soa_server1.out'>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:28 PM ART> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 16.0-b13 from Sun Microsystems Inc.>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:28 PM ART> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.2.0  Tue Oct 20 12:16:15 PDT 2009 1267925 >  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM ART> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090065> <Getting boot identity from user.>  
Enter username to boot WebLogic server:Enter password to boot WebLogic server:  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM ART> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:  

There are 1 nested errors:  

weblogic.management.ManagementException: Booting as admin server, but servername, soa_server1, does not match the admin server name, AdminServer  
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(RuntimeAccessService.java:67)  
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)  
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)  
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:749)  
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:488)  
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:446)  
    at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)  

>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM ART> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM ART> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM ART> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <Waiting for the process to die: 31144>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server failed during startup so will not be restarted>  
<Mar 15, 2010 3:33:30 PM> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <runMonitor returned, setting finished=true and notifying waiters>
```

The commands to start the servers and each result are:

```
$wlst.sh  
>startNodeManager()  
Successfully started  
>nmConnect(......)  
Successfully connected  
>nmStart('AdminServer')  
Successfully started  
>nmStart('soa_server1')  
Given error...
```

When I start the servers using the scripts it works correctly:

```
$nohup $WL_HOME/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh > nodemanager.out &  
$nohup $MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/soa_domain/startWebLogic.sh > adminserver.out &  
$nohup $MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/soa_domain/bin/startManagedServer.sh soa_server > soa_server.out &
```

Do you have any clue of what is happening? If you need more info, just ask for it.

thanks in advance

Comment: > Booting as admin server, but servername, soa_server1, does not match the admin server name, AdminServer  

What is the command line you are using to start the server?

Did you enroll the NodeManager into the domain?

Can you start the server from Administrative Console?

Comment: How do I check if I enrolled the NodeManager into the domain? I don't know what you mean by that.
Now you mention it, I can't start the Administrative Console. It might be listening only from localhost? How can I check that?

Comment: This problem is related with this post in OTN: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1041463&tstart=0&messageID=4169586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was running wlst.sh from my home directory. wlst.sh must be run from $WL_HOME/common/nodemanager directory, because it uses the nodemanager.properties in the current directory.

The nodemanager.properties that solved my problem looks like this:

```
DomainsFile=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager/nodemanager.domains  
LogLimit=0  
PropertiesVersion=10.3  
AuthenticationEnabled=true  
NodeManagerHome=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager  
JavaHome=/u01/app/oracle/jrmc-3.1.2-1.6.0/jre  
#JavaHome=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18  
#LogLevel=INFO  
DomainsFileEnabled=true  
StartScriptName=startWebLogic.sh  
ListenAddress=  
NativeVersionEnabled=true  
ListenPort=5556  
LogToStderr=true  
SecureListener=true  
LogCount=1  
StopScriptEnabled=false  
QuitEnabled=false  
#LogAppend=true  
LogAppend=false  
StateCheckInterval=500  
#CrashRecoveryEnabled=false  
CrashRecoveryEnabled=true  
StartScriptEnabled=true  
LogFile=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.1/mw/wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager/nodemanager.log  
LogFormatter=weblogic.nodemanager.server.LogFormatter  
ListenBacklog=50
```

Answer (score 2):

My nodemanager was launched as a daemon service, and NODEMGR_HOME variable was properly set, but still error was the same.

For me the solution was to run managed server at least once with additional argument:

```
arg="Arguments=\" -Dweblogic.management.server=localhost:7001\""
prps=makePropertiesObject(arg)
nmStart(ManagedServerName,props=prps)
```

Nodemanager stores the arguments, and next time simple `nmStart(ManagedServerName)` works fine.

The same result (additional Arguments stored by nodemanager) is achieved with doing steps (this action is sufficient to perform one time):

  1. run nodemanager

  2. run admin server

  3. go to admin /console and run managed server from there

  3.a (or wlst: connect to admin and run managed)

But in this case your domain has to be configured to use that nodemanager

```
cd('/')
create(MachineName, 'Machine')
cd('Machine/' + MachineName)
create(MachineName, 'NodeManager')
cd('NodeManager/' + MachineName)
set('ListenAddress', MachineIP)
cd('/')
cd('Server/' + ManagedServerName)
set('Machine', Machine1Name)
```