# WebLogic Managed server fails to start

Tags: weblogic

Using WebLogic 12.1.2 on a Oracle Linux 6 server, I am attempting to start managed server managedServer1 by calling the managed startup script below.

```
./startManagedWebLogic.sh managedServer1 http://adminServerURL:7001
```

When ran, the server fails to start with the following error.

```
<Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:
There are 1 nested errors:
weblogic.management.ManagementException: Booting as admin server, but servername, managedServer1, does not match the admin server name, admin
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService.start(RuntimeAccessService.java:67)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:895)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:572)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:471)
    at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:74)
```

I have checked multiple online resources of other users getting the same error (ex. [Can't start managed server in Oracle Weblogic 10.3.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/122741/cant-start-managed-server-in-oracle-weblogic-10-3-2)) however, they are all related to Node Manager. In my case, I am not using Node Manager and trying to start the server manually via startup script. Also, this error happens for any managed server I try to start. If I put an invalid admin url, the error still occurs. Which tells me the issue is happening before it even attempts to connect to the admin server. So far I have done the following troubleshooting steps.

- Recreated managed server's boot.properties file and verified it has the correct permissions.
- Checked config.xml file but can not find any red flags. Admin server starts without any issues.
- Delete DOMAIN_HOME/servers/managedServer1 folder and let the folders be recreated when trying to start the managed server. Did not expect this to work since it generates this error for all managed server names I supply to the startup script.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestions on anything else I could check that may be the cause of this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: How have you created the managed servers? via `pack`/`unpack` or using WLST `writeTemplate()`? any other way? at all?

Comment: We created them through the WebLogic console. However we found our issue and have posted as my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Somehow the setDomainEnv.sh script got corrupted. When we replaced it with a working file, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when removing the following lines in setDomainEnv.sh :

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${JAVA_PROPERTIES} -DmyOption1 -DmyOption2"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

If you added custom options in the line and want to remove them, make sure to restore the original lines :

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${JAVA_PROPERTIES}"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Otherwise, it tries to start the managed server as as admin server.